# Media monkey doesn't play m4a

Tags: windows, music, m4a, mediamonkey

I have a number of songs on my Windows computer that were copied over from Ubuntu. My mp3's work fine in Media Monkey, but none of my m4a's do. As I guess I believe that it might have something do with incorrect tagging. Is there any program that will help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Quicktime installed? MM needs it to play m4a.

Some other suggestions can be found in this forum thread

> [MediaMonkey doesn't play .m4a](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=165696)

Answer (score 1):

The current version of MediaMonkey (3.2+) will play M4A tracks using Quicktime (assuming it's installed).

Alternatively, an AAC plugin can be purchased via the addons section of the site.