# m4a file with Quicktime: Error - 2041: an invalid sample description was found in the movie

Tags: music, quicktime, m4a

I have a number of m4a files that don't play properly. I [previously thought that it was a problem with Media Monkey](https://superuser.com/questions/178260/media-monkey-doesnt-play-m4a), but I managed to get Media Monkey to play some m4a files and the files I know don't run in Media Monkey, iTunes, Quicktime or Media Player. Most of these players fail without useful information, but Quicktime gives the message in the title. The files that fail were originally ripped from CD on Ubuntu. Is there anyway I can fix up these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread : 
[error -2041: an invalid sample description was found in the movie](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7691819).

Some people reported that the problem was fixed by changing the file's postfix to .3gp, while others have proposed heavier solutions that fix the encoded video file, using software such as [mp4UI](http://mp4ui.sourceforge.net/), VLC or [Mobile Media Convert](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm).

Question: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Thanks, I will try this when I get home

Comment: Mobile Media Converter worked great